# DropDown list with translated values

Tags: model-view-controller

I have enums in my domain like this

```
public enum AdTypeEnum { Sale = 1, Rent = 2, SaleOrRent = 3 };
```

In my view I'm rendering this enums like this

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AdType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyDomain.Domain.Property.AdTypeEnum))))
</div>
```

Now, what I'm trying to achive is based on selected language I want to display these enums in drop down list in selected language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
public static Array Localize(Array values)
{
 string[] result = new string[values.Length];
 for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
  result[i] = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(values.GetValue(i).ToString());

 return result;
}
```

A better implementation should use a different key-set for each enum type (using the enum name as part of the GetString() parameter).
Anyway this method is pretty naive, I think for a big application (or for more complex scenarios) you may need to inherit from SelectList class.